# Hibernate Reverse Engineering not generating domain classes for all tables from given database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, reverse-engineering, jboss-tools

Here i have specified to hibernate code generator to create domain classes for all the tables present in stocksdata and exclude 2 of them, the code doesnt works and generates nothing !
please help !

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-catalog="stocksdata" match-name="user" exclude="true"/>
  <table-filter match-catalog="stocksdata" match-name="hibernate_sequence" exclude="true"/>
  <table-filter match-catalog="stocksdata" match-schema="stocksdata" match-name=".*"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNddl.png)

Comment: Can you update your question to provide a sample of the data present in your database, including both records you want included in your result _and_ records you want to filter out? Additionally, if you're getting any error messages, please include them as well.

Comment: @superhawk610 i want to create entity class of all these tables,
<table-filter match-catalog="stocksdata" match-schema="stocksdata" match-name=".*"/>
using this is not helping me, i need to specify match name in order to generate class

Comment: would this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404219/hibernate-reverse-engineering-any-smart-way-to-exclude-unnecessary-columns

Comment: @Tschallacka i have 50 tables, 
 <table-filter match-catalog="stocksdata" match-schema="stocksdata" match-name=".*"/> 
using above line is not helping me to generate any pojo class